# How can I execute MapReduce on MATLAB R2014a?

Tags: mapreduce

How can I execute MapReduce on MATLAB R2014a?

Because I think MATLAB R2014a does not support DataStore, Map, and Reduce functions.

Comment: Hi everyone, please, anybody have an idea How can I execute MapReduce Functions {Map & Reduce} on MATLAB R2014a ? Because I think MATLAB R2014a does not support DataStore, Map, and Reduce functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. The functionality for datastore and mapreduce was introduced in MATLAB R2014b. So you cannot use these functions with R2014a.

For more info, see the Release Notes:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html